# Проблема с подключением webenginewidgets в .pro-файле (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

Использую Qt версии 6.2.0, WebEngine в Qt Maintenance Tool установлен. Прописываю `QT += webenginewidgets` в .pro, но Qt мне пишет

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: positioning

Скриншот используемого комплекта прикрепляю:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFd93.png)

Что мне делать?

Comment: Переустановил Qt 6.2.0 - ошибка пропала. Пока оставлю открытой тему, пока не удостоверюсь, что все работает.

Comment: Все работает. А ларчик просто открывался...

Answer (score 0):

Решение - переустановка Qt 6.2.0

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).